# Update Fields Automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

I'm pretty new here and usually don't resort to forum post unless I really can't figure things out by searching for a solution on my own but I'm stuck. I work in an IT department and I am developing a tool that will be used to compare across three data pulls to see where we are missing data. All data is supposed to be accounted for in all three databases so we need to find discrepancies where it does not match. This is data used across all of our car dealerships and it is pulled from three providers who give it to us. (Example: Our website listing, cars actually on sale in our inventory, and the third deals with web listings on other sites).

Unfortunately, whenever we do an export from each site the dealership locations do not match with the exact same syntax. I have all three tables in a sql database that is reuploaded by the user each month. I have case statements written so I can run a query to change each matching dealership in a way that matches syntax across all three tables. For example 'Ford Denham' and 'Denham Ford' are all changed to 'ASFD' which is an acronym we use for that dealership.

Now we have reports which I have created with SQL Report Builder. My problem is, all of my queries are written as if the Location is always 'ASFD' so I can match records based on location. When the user uploads data how can I automatically have my Case Statement run on the new files in the database without having to trigger the query myself? If I don't run the Case Statement rename then none of the reports will run correctly because Locations do not match correctly.

Thank you for any help. Let me know if I should have gone about this a different way since I have never really posted here before. I tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Can you define a mapping table and capture your case statements as data in there? For example, a new table called LocationMap will have two columns: `incoming_data` and `internal_location`. So, it will have rows like `incoming_data='Ford Denhan', internal_location='ASFD'` and so forth for all your case statement mappings. Then, you rewrite your query to join with this table which will return correct `internal_location` for all defined free style data. I'm thinking if you can define them in a case statement, it should be possible to capture them in a data table.

Comment: I'll look into this when I get back to work tomorrow. I'll get back to you if I can put something together with your thought process.

Comment: @WiSeeker thank you for your help. Even though I hold myself to a standard of high technology knowledge, I haven't worked much with SQL since I left college level courses two years ago. After meeting with my COO and a group of people today, I learned that SQL allows you to create triggers which run each time a change is made. We are using a different provider to upload our data and by adding a trigger to our database pull I can update names very easily. Thank you for your help regardless!

Comment: That will work well too. I'm used to production environments where it is easier to add/remove rows of data than to make changes to code (say stored proc or trigger). So, I'm used to looking for data-driven approaches. Triggers can be used to achieve what you're after.